# Error 1215: Can't add foreign key constraint (InnoDB)

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, innodb

I'm struggling around to create a foreign key with the following query:

```
alter table `users` add constraint `users_sales_partner_id_foreign` foreign key (`sales_partner_id`) references `structures` (`sales_partner_id`) on update cascade
```

InnoDB log says, it can't match this index:

> 2017-02-27 10:25:47 Error in foreign key constraint of
>   table website_backend/users: foreign key
>   (`sales_partner_id`) references `structures` (`sales_partner_id`) on update cascade:
>   Cannot find an index in the referenced table where the referenced
>   columns appear as the first columns, or column types in the table and
>   the referenced table do not match for constraint.

I have already checked typos and data type incompatibility, but everything seems to be alright:

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `profile_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `sales_partner_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(191) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(191) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `state` enum('pending','confirmed','active','deactivated') COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `users_profile_id_unique` (`profile_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `users_sales_partner_id_unique` (`sales_partner_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `users_email_unique` (`email`),
  CONSTRAINT `users_profile_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`profile_id`) REFERENCES `profiles` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci

CREATE TABLE `structures` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `sales_partner_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `sales_partner_structure` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `active` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `blocked` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

I can't get my problem, does somebody have a clue? Thanks in advance!

Comment: The referenced column should be indexed. But (usually) it should also be unique. Are you sure that this FK matches the relation correctly?

Comment: Well, you're right concerning the uniqueness: The problem is that `sales_partner_id` is not unique in `structures` due to the customer's previous structure. But I thought InnoDB should deal with that anyway.

Comment: So why do you want to define that FK? It doesn't seam reasonable to me. You could define a non unique index on `structures(sales_partner_id)` and your ALTER statement will work after that. But I'm pretty sure you are trying to do something really wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Paul Spiegel for his reminding that I can only set FKs to the indexed fields. After another review I noticed that my referenced field was not indexed, that solved my problem.